# Problem With WindowStyle and ProcessStartInfo 

Tags: c#, process

I am using this code right now:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process process = new Process();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    startInfo.FileName = @"D:\קוד C#\WindowsFormsApplication11\WindowsFormsApplication11\obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication11.exe";
   // startInfo.Arguments = "-console -game cstrike +map de_dust +maxplayers 16 -port 27017";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo; 
    process.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
}
```

The code is actually working very well, but the problem is:

When I start the program (by clicking `button1`) the program runs as "hidden" (as I want). But how can I change it to not be in `hidden` mode?

Another question:

What about if the program can't get into `hidden` mode? What can I do then?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Does it get hidden when you press Button2?

Comment: if you want to change the Window after process is started, you can get the window with FindWindow Win32 API, and than change its visibility...

Comment: The Process Go hidden only when i press button 1. when i press button 2 nothing happnds, its suppuse to get Maximized;

Comment: StartInfo is used for the process starting, I don't think it effects the process after starting. You're going to need to go get the window handle using Win32 (as Amittai stated) and then manipulate it that way.

Comment: any chance you got any guild?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way of doing this is by putting a system tray icon in. Once your program is hidden you make the system tray icon available, and put the action for showing the window again in a context menu on the tray icon.

Comment: i agree. i didnt think about it, but. i will be happy to know the way to do this, just for knowlage. if i wanted to to a system tray, i can just do this.hide(). thanks

Comment: http://jameskovacs.com/2006/01/11/how-to-minimize-to-the-system-tray/ this might help you a bit.

Comment: i dont need system tray(i know it very well acuily) i want to know my first quiston, that i explind in the quiton blow.